# How to fix the ValueError: n_splits=10 Error sklearn NLP

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm trying to make `multi class classification` for first time and I used scikit-learn for the first time , I find  [this code](https://medium.com/swlh/multi-class-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-a9bacb751048)  online and trying to use that for my data
my data look like this

```
id                      Text                                           Tags
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Tears made her vision blur again                                  blue
2    She looked away, outside, at the blur of snow as he continued.    blue
3    Mr. Green, you are wanted on the phone                            green
4    I prefer oranges to apples                                        orange
5    Tom drank his orange juice                                        black
```

this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

df = pd.read_csv('./dataSet03.csv')
col = ['Text', 'Tags']
data = df[col]
data.columns =['Text', 'Tags']
df['id'] = df['Tags'].factorize()[0]
product_id_data = df[['Tags', 'id']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('id')
product_to_id = dict(product_id_data.values)
id_to_product = dict(product_id_data[['id', 'Tags']].values)
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, 
                        min_df=5, 
                        norm='l2', 
                        encoding='latin-1', 
                        ngram_range=(1, 2),
                        stop_words='english')
features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.Text).toarray()
labels = df.id
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.Text, df.Tags, random_state=0)
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
models = [
    RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, max_depth=3, random_state=0),
    LinearSVC(),#Linear Support Vector Classification.
    MultinomialNB(),#Naive Bayes classifier for multinomial models
    LogisticRegression(random_state=0),
]
CV = 10
cv_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(CV * len(models)))
entries = []
for model in models:
    model_name = model.__class__.__name__
    accuracies = cross_val_score(model, features, labels, scoring='accuracy', cv=CV)
    for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
        entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
cv_df = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=['model_name', 'fold_idx', 'accuracy'])
print(cv_df.groupby('model_name').accuracy.mean())
```

my code got this error when reach this line

```
accuracies = cross_val_score(model, features, labels, scoring='accuracy', cv=CV)
```

this is the error

```
ValueError: n_splits=10 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class.
```

Comment: Logistic regression, by default, is limited to two-class classification problems. Try removing it and use only 3 remaining models.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `id` as a training label, which looks like a unique entry from your example, so this makes absolutely no sense at all. You will be having as many class as the number of observations.

Most likely you want to use `Tags`, below is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'Text':['Tears made her vision'
                           'blur again, She looked', 
                           'away, outside',
                           'at the blur of snow',
                           'as he continued.',
                           'Mr. Green, you are',
                           'wanted on the phone',
                           'I prefer oranges',
                           'to apples',
                           'Tom drank his',
                           'orange juice'],
                   'Tags':['blue','blue','green','orange','green','orange','blue','green','orange','blue']
                  })
```

Running your code with CV=3:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.Text).toarray()
labels = df.Tags

models = [
    RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, max_depth=3, random_state=0),
    LinearSVC(),#Linear Support Vector Classification.
    MultinomialNB(),#Naive Bayes classifier for multinomial models
    LogisticRegression(random_state=0),
]
CV = 3
#cv_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(CV * len(models)))
entries = []
for model in models:
    model_name = model.__class__.__name__
    accuracies = cross_val_score(model, features, labels, scoring='accuracy', cv=CV)
    for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
        entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
cv_df = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=['model_name', 'fold_idx', 'accuracy'])
print(cv_df.groupby('model_name').accuracy.mean())
```

In this example, there's not enough data to run CV=10, but as long as there are at least 10 members of each class, you can run CV=10. Code above gives this output:

```
model_name
LinearSVC                 0.222222
LogisticRegression        0.222222
MultinomialNB             0.388889
RandomForestClassifier    0.388889
Name: accuracy, dtype: float64
```